# Kotlin Flow - Nullable value

Tags: android, android-room, androidx, kotlin-flow

Is it possible to check if Flow sends back a value and to act on it if it doesn't?

```
override suspend fun insertUserResponse(userResponse: UserResponse) {
    val userResponseFromBDD: Flow<UserResponse>? = userResponseDAO.searchUserByToken(userResponse.profilePOJO.uniqueID)
    userResponseFromBDD?.collect {
        userResponseDAO.updateUser(userResponse)
    } ?: {
        userResponseDAO.insertUser(userResponse)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several remarks:

1. There are two types of queries - one-shot and streams. For your use-case you need one-shot query (to ge response or null once with `searchUserByToken` and once - to insert or update value). For one-shot queries in `Room` you can use suspend function with no `Flow`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM userResponse where id = :id")
suspend fun searchUserByToken(id: Int):UserResponse?
```

And your code with checking value would be:

```
override suspend fun insertUserResponse(userResponse: UserResponse) {
    val userResponseFromBDD = userResponseDAO.searchUserByToken(userResponse.profilePOJO.uniqueID)
    userResponseFromBDD?.let { userResponseDAO.updateUser(userResponse)} 
      ?: userResponseDAO.insertUser(userResponse)
}
```

2. With Flow you get stream, that issues values whenever data is updated in DB. That's why in your use-case you can get values in loop: you get value value from `searchUserByToken`  -> you update value -> you get new value since Room uses Flow and invokes `searchUserByToken` again -> you update value -> ...
3. If you use Room's `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` you can not to check if userResponse is in DB and use just `insertUser` method (since if user is in db insert would cause it's update)

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this! It really helped me to understand Flow in a better way!
Also, thank you for editing my question.